# YouTube API - Video Upload - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, youtube-api

This is driving me crazy! I am using the following code below. **90% of the time** I get the following error. Every now and then it works with no problem. Please help. I checked the Developer Key, Username and Password.

> Error: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error:
>   (401) Unauthorized.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at
>   Google.GData.Client.ResumableUpload.ResumableUploader.UploadStreamPart(Int32
>   partIndex, String httpMethod, Uri sessionUri, Authenticator
>   authentication, Stream payload, String mediaType, AsyncData data)
>   at
>   Google.GData.Client.ResumableUpload.ResumableUploader.UploadStream(String
>   httpMethod, Uri sessionUri, Authenticator authentication, Stream
>   payload, String mediaType, AsyncData data)    at
>   Google.GData.Client.ResumableUpload.ResumableUploader.Insert(Authenticator
>   authentication, AbstractEntry payload, AsyncData data)    at
>   Google.GData.Client.ResumableUpload.ResumableUploader.AsyncInsertWorker(AsyncResumableUploadData
>   data, AsyncOperation asyncOp, SendOrPostCallback
>   completionMethodDelegate) Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   inputStream can not be null

```
                **My Code:**

                newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Nonprofit", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
                newVideo.Description = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
                ResumableUploader m_ResumableUploader = null;
                Authenticator YouTubeAuthenticator;

                m_ResumableUploader = new ResumableUploader(100); //chunksize 1 MB
                m_ResumableUploader.AsyncOperationCompleted += new AsyncOperationCompletedEventHandler(m_ResumableUploader_AsyncOperationCompleted);
                m_ResumableUploader.AsyncOperationProgress += new AsyncOperationProgressEventHandler(m_ResumableUploader_AsyncOperationProgress);

                YouTubeAuthenticator = new ClientLoginAuthenticator(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPLICATION_NAME"].ToString(), ServiceNames.YouTube, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LOGIN_USERNAME"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LOGIN_PASSWORD"].ToString());

                YouTubeAuthenticator.DeveloperKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DEVELOPER_KEY"].ToString();
                string contentType = MediaFileSource.GetContentTypeForFileName(fileName);
                newVideo.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(filePath, contentType);

                AtomLink link = new AtomLink("http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YT_USERNAME"].ToString() + "/uploads");
                link.Rel = ResumableUploader.CreateMediaRelation;
                newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Links.Add(link);

                m_ResumableUploader.InsertAsync(YouTubeAuthenticator, newVideo.YouTubeEntry, new object());
```

I think I should add.. It breaks on the last line ytr.ParseVideo(e.ResponseStream);

```
void m_ResumableUploader_AsyncOperationCompleted(object sender, AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

                YouTubeRequestSettings ys = new YouTubeRequestSettings(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPLICATION_NAME"].ToString(),
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DEVELOPER_KEY"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LOGIN_USERNAME"].ToString(),
                                                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LOGIN_PASSWORD"].ToString());

                YouTubeRequest ytr = new YouTubeRequest(ys);
                Video v = ytr.ParseVideo(e.ResponseStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you're not uploading into the account that corresponds to the stored credentials that you have. In general, you shouldn't do things like `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YT_USERNAME"].ToString()` in your GData API v2 code; instead, you should use the value `default` as the user portion of a URL, which refers to the currently authenticated user.